# I replaced an FTP server, and now I can't upload files in vb6 ftp api function

Tags: ftp, vb6

I replaced an FTP server, and now I can't upload files.
The code was written on vb6.
The exact same code that works with the old server, doesn't work with the new server.
In the process of uploading the file (FtpOpenFile), I see that it creates a new empty file in the destination, but does not return the file ID that can fill the file.
Below is the code, thank you very much for your help.

```
Private Declare Function InternetOpen Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" (ByVal sAgent As String, ByVal lAccessType As Long, ByVal sProxyName As String, ByVal sProxyBypass As String, ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function InternetConnect Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetConnectA" (ByVal hInternetSession As Long, ByVal sServerName As String, ByVal nServerPort As Integer, ByVal sUserName As String, ByVal sPassword As String, ByVal lService As Long, ByVal lFlags As Long, ByVal lContext As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FtpOpenFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpOpenFileA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, ByVal sBuff As String, ByVal Access As Long, ByVal flags As Long, ByVal Context As Long) As Long

Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG = 0
Const INTERNET_INVALID_PORT_NUMBER = 0
Const INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP = 1
Public Const FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY = &H2



Public Function UploadFile()

.
.
.    
    hInternet = InternetOpen(scUserAgent, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
    hConnection = InternetConnect(hInternet, sServerName, INTERNET_INVALID_PORT_NUMBER, sUserName, sPassword, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0)

    hFile = FtpOpenFile(hConnection, RemoteFile, &H40000000, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0)

    If hFile = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to create the remote file."
        Exit Function
    End If


End Function
```

The problem is that hFile returns 0 instead of a unique file ID on the server as it reads on the old server.

```
ExtraFTP log:
Status: Resolving address of ftp-new......co.il
Status: Connecting to 185.185.133.52:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER ....-ftp
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS ***************
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Starting upload of C:\temp\009\Be072222.mdb
Command:    CWD /michlol/HomeMI
Response:   250 CWD command successful.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (185,185,133,52,199,44).
Command:    STOR Be072222.mdb
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Response:   226 Transfer complete.
Status: File transfer successful
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (185,185,133,52,199,45).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Response:   226 Transfer complete.
Status: Directory listing successful
```

Comment: _**Return Value** Returns a handle if successful, or NULL [ie 0] otherwise. To retrieve a specific error message, call `GetLastError`._ In VB6 `GetLastError` is `err.lastdllerror`.

Comment: Also, can you upload the files using any FTP client at all?

Comment: Thanks, i checked the error is: 12002  The request has timed out.

Comment: I can't use FTP client, because this code is just part of a big program where clients upload the files to my server.

Comment: I'm asking if you have even tested that the FTP server is working as you expect.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I didn't understand you, in using ExtraFTP I can upload files very quickly.

Comment: So show us a log file from ExtraFTP + Show us how that log corresponds to your VB code (how values of your variables match the paths and addresses in the log file).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/ftp-sessions _The application establishes an ftp session by calling InternetConnect on a handle created by InternetOpen. InternetConnect needs the server name, ftp port number, user name, password, and service type (which must be set to INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP). For **passive ftp semantics**, the application must also set the **INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE** flag._. On your other computer the firewall must have been configured to allow normal ftp.

Comment: Normal FTP both computers are servers and clients. Firewalls block incoming requests to servers. So the FTP host cannot get to connect back to you. In passive ftp the host is a server on both channels meaning you initiate all connections keeping firewalls happy.

Comment: Amazing! It works!
Thank you very much!

Comment: _Amazing_ that following the technical specification works?